# utorrent stops internet traffic

Tags: windows, speed, tcpip, utorrent

this is a new problem for me, and I really don't know how to fix it.

From time to time i'm using uTorrent for file transfers, but in the past month when i start utorrent, i cannot navigate anymore on the web, even if the utorrent doesn't download or upload anything.

also i have a router, and i think the problem can be related to it. Do you have any idea about what can i do in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows only allows a certain amount of concurrent TCP/IP connections and uTorrents eats them all up, leaving your browser thinking it cannot connect to the internet. You can mess with the uTorrent settings  or Windows, but I don't recommend either. You are probably better off pausing uTorrent when you are surfing.

You can confirm this by checking your event log (Start -> Run -> eventvwr) look for TCP/IP messages like

> "TCP/IP has reached the security limit
>   imposed on the number of concurrent
>   TCP connect attempts."

Also try [EVENT_TCPIP_TCP_CONNECT_LIMIT_REACHED](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=4226&EvtSrc=Tcpip&LCID=1033)

Comment: many thx, you save me. Indeed, utorrent has taken all the TCP Connections. Also many thx for the envent viewer tips. Very very useful :)

Comment: no probs :D glad i could help

Comment: uTorrent has a Scheduler in its Prefs that you can use to throttle the connections and bandwidth it uses at certain times of day. You can set it to limit its bandwidth at times that you're using the PC (and during peak times when your ISP limits downloads) and then unleash full speed at times you don't use it.

Comment: seriously, the answer is to STOP using uTorrent?  why can't someone just figure out how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details - Router, ISP E.t.c.

It could really be anything - Sometimes torrents create to many active connections and it makes the internet go so slow. Try disabling a firewall (if you have one) and see if that helps as I know of a few that have limits on how many connections can be open.

Also, If you are in the UK and use the Virgin/NTL router/modem (up to the half sized black box) and it is straight in to the pc without another router in between, I know for a fact that you get this sort of problem when using torrents and the only way to fix is to get a router to plug in between them.