# bandwidth problem with utorrent

Tags: utorrent

I think utorrent has been consuming lots of bandwidth and my connection is not that fast.
How do I set it so that it consumes the less possible bandwidth?
I've tried setting its download  and upload limit to 1kbps. Together with the download bandwidth allocation set to low. I even exited utorrent but it seems that it is still consuming lots of bandwidth. How do I solve this one?

Comment: You might want to look at http://superuser.com/questions/48036/utorrent-stops-internet-traffic which may help. Not *really* a duplicate, but it might help.

Comment: Why are you bothering to use uTorrent at all, then? At 1kb/s it'll take 17 minutes to download 1 MB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that closing uTorrent via the [x] at the top right doesn't actually exit the program. It closes the UI but keeps the process running - there should be an icon in the system tray.

To completely close uTorrent you have to select **File > Exit**.

Answer (score 2):

Try to limit the number of max connections. A lot of routers/modems have a limited number of connections they support (Windows does too by the way).

uTorrent can make lots and lots of connections, resulting in a slow network no matter if you actually download/upload at all.

Comment: I also tried that and I put a value of 1. But connection is still suffering.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried setting its download and upload limit to 1kbps.

I believe that affects only the actual torrent data exchange.
You might also want to turn off DHT.

Answer (score 0):

Devices like home routers usually have problems when it comes to high number of simultaneous connections. Having many open connections is way more of a problem than bandwidth. Limit the number of open connection to 80 from your .torrent client.
It should be enough to up/down and not overkill anything in the process.

When you don'y use it, exit it (by right click and exit), as said by ChrisF.